# OneToOne Relation

Tags: mysql, linux, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am working on Ubuntu linux. I am trying to create my first symfony project, in which I had to establish a OneToOne bidirectional relation using annotations between my users and events entity. I am unable to tell if the relationship has been established properly. Is there a way to check that, by using terminal commands?

Comment: If the doctrine:schema:update` (or :create) command didn't outputed any errors, it should be fine. The easiest way to verify is to use it in PHP. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me, these steps are mandatory once changes to entities are made:

- `doctrine:mapping:info` - all entities must return `[OK]`
- `doctrine:schema:validate` - it must return `[Mapping]  OK - The mapping files are correct.`. **Note:** You might encounter `FAIL - The database schema is not in sync...` but I wouldn't worry much about it if have already made changes to database (some sort of sync).
- Insert some dummy data, fetch the "left side" of relationship via dummy/existing controller and `var_dump` it. That should give you *some* raw idea
- Finally, fetch the right side of relationship. This will ensure that potential `Proxy` object is being resolved and formalized into concrete object.

Hope this help :)